# Initialising with "undef" for self-documenting code?

Tags: perl, undef

Sometimes I'd like to write:

```
my $var = shift // undef;    # argument is optional
                             # or

my $var = $val{optional_value} // undef;
```

to indicate that it is ok to have the argument missing, otherwise `// undef` is useless, of course.

How expensive is this, is it optimized away by the compiler?

Comment: you may want to cast a benchmark to find out that.

Comment: I would be most likely to assume it was a mistake if I saw that in production code. Stick to comments if you feel they're needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions: Not and no.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure it's not very expensive, but I have to say that

```
my $var = shift // undef;
```

is not nearly as clear as

```
my $var = shift;    # argument is optional
```

or

```
my $var = shift;    # optional; undef if omitted
```

Which are both definitely (although barely) cheaper at runtime.  If you need the comment anyway (for clarity), then what does `// undef` really add except unnecessary opcodes?

Comment: I added the comments only here, in the example.

Comment: @Sadko, I suspected as much, which is why my example didn't have a comment.  The `// undef` may be clear to you, but I doubt it will be to anyone else reading your code.  The comments, on the other hand, should be clear to anyone.

Comment: True. I was thinking about a reminder for myself. For other readers a comment is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a benchmark:

```
use strict;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

sub shu
{
    my $x = shift // undef;
    return $x // 0;
}

sub sh
{
    my $x = shift;
    return $x // 0;
}

timethese ( 100_000_000, { shu => \&shu, sh => \&sh } );

# outputs:

# Benchmark: timing 100000000 iterations of sh, shu...
#    sh:  14 wallclock secs (14.95 usr + -0.06 sys = 14.89 CPU) @ 6715916.72/s (n=100000000)
#    shu: 16 wallclock secs (16.74 usr + -0.02 sys = 16.72 CPU) @ 5980861.24/s (n=100000000)
```

So the results confirm what was said above.